# can i use the MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION mode in GINGERBREAD or ECLAIR?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I want to detect that there is a `VoIP` call is been established, I am using this code

```
AudioManager Audio =  (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
int mode = Audio.getMode();
```

this code is working fine on API level 11 and above as mentioned in Android|Developers
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION

Is there any way to detect the `MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION` mode in older APIs?

Comment: this mode MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION  is not working even in android 4.0.4!!!! is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there any way to detect the MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION mode in older APIs. Look at this SIP-based VoIP http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.3.html 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html
Hope this helps.